# Finding the Galois Group of a field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I am trying to find Galois Group of field extension $\mathbb{Q}$($2^{1/4}$)/$\mathbb{Q}$($2^{1/2}$).

I know it is a quadratic extension and hence Galois extension but how can I find its Galois Group?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: When $a$ is in the base field then $\sqrt{a}$ is sent to $\pm  \sqrt{a}$.

Comment: So I can conclude that (2)^(1/4) is sent to ±  (2)^(1/4) right?

Comment: Yes, what is mysterious to you? If $b^2=a$ then $\sigma(b)^2=a$ when $\sigma$ is an automorphism such that $\sigma(a)=a$.

Comment: Okay now I understood thank you vey much!!

Comment: You can use the degree theorem with the third field equal to $\Bbb Q$, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735996/show-that-mathbbq21-4-mathbbq-is-not-galois-prove-that-mathbb). So the Galois group must have order $2$, hence must be isomorphic to $C_2$.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!